# Why when running over a map entries then destructure is made by [] and not by {}

Tags: javascript, dictionary, destructor, braces

lets say i have the following **Map**:

```
const question = new Map([
  ['question', 'What is the best programming language in the world?'],
  [1, 'C'],
  [2, 'Java'],
  [3, 'JavaScript'],
  ['correct', 3],
  [true, 'Correct '],
  [false, 'Try again!'],

]);
```

when i want to itereate over all the entires i'm writing:

```
for (const [key, value] of question) {
  if (typeof key === 'number') console.log(`Answer ${key}: ${value}`);
```

My question is why i'm writing **[key,value]** and not **{key,value}** since all entry is an object with key,value. When i printing to console **console.log(question.entries()) i see that all the entries looks like: {key: 1, value:"c"} and not like [1,"c"]. So why destructuring isn't an object destructure but an array destructure?

Comment: Most browsers implement a special display for the map iterator, but the values yielded are arrays of two elements, not objects.

Comment: @Aplet123, it is not a browser specific implementation rather than the language specification as standard.

Comment: every entry is an array, 
see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#iterating_over_a_jsxrefmap

Comment: @NinaScholz The values yielded by the iterator are standardized; [the way the console displays the iterator](https://i.imgur.com/GD248XD.png) is not

Comment: You can use `Object.fromEntries(question)` to give you back a plain JS object if that's what you're looking for. I believe the reason Map entries are arrays and not objects is because of how Map is implemented using [Symbol.Iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) (along with Array, Set, etc., but not Object).

Comment: This is literally the first thing that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map explains: "*A Map object iterates its elements in insertion order — a for...of loop returns an array of [key, value] for each iteration.*" =)

Comment: Is it right to say that a map is a double array? cause again the browser display is as `[[entries]]`?

Comment: "*Is it right to say that a map is a double array?*" no, it's not. A map is an exotic object. `[[entries]]` is just how the browser represents its internal data structure. The standard  for maps specifies that it should have sub-linear lookups which you cannot have with a simple array.

Comment: @VLAZ, ok.. Thanks!